# Error C2432 illegal reference to 16-bit data in 'second operand' of __asm

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly, inline-assembly, 32-bit

In Visual Studio, I get this error when I compile my __asm in C. Does anybody know what is wrong with this code? I tried everything, but nothing works. I am trying to implement the bubble sort in assembly.

```
unsigned short i = 0;
unsigned short j = 0;
unsigned short max = short(N-2);


unsigned short tab[5];
tab[0] = 54;
tab[1] = 123;
tab[2] = 342;
tab[3] = 5436;
tab[4] = 1234;

unsigned short a = 0;

__asm {
loop1:
    inc i
    mov j, 0

        mov si, tab

        loop2:
            mov ax, [si] // <- Error C2432 on this line 
            mov a, ax

            inc j
            mov ax, j
            mov bx, max
            cmp ax, bx
            jz cdnloop2
        loop loop2
        cdnloop2:
    mov ax, i
    mov bx, max
    cmp ax, bx
    jz endof

    loop loop1  
endof :
}
```

Comment: Memory addresses are 32 bits. (Or 64 bits if you're compiling the program as 64 bits)

Comment: Does `mov ax, word ptr [si]` solve it?

Comment: Why do you use 16 bit assembly in 32 bit code?

Comment: The address register have to be 32 bit or 64 bit. Use `mov ax, [esi]` or `mov ax, [rsi]`.

Comment: @Weather Vane: doesn't work

Comment: @immibis: maybe that is a problem, do you know what a data type in C lang take me 32 bits and work in __asm? i compile this project as 32bits (x86)

Comment: @pabix The problem is not with C, the problem is with your assembly. `si` is a 16-bit register. If your program was entirely written in assembly, without any C at all, `mov ax, [si]` still wouldn't be allowed.

Comment: @immibis technically `mov ax, [si]` is allowed in 32 bit mode with an address size override prefix (`66 67 8B 04`). Probably won't make any sense, but it's allowed.

Comment: @DirkWolfgangGlomp . In this case `mov ax, [esi]` and usage of _ESI_ (instead of _SI_) in general is the way to go. The code in question isn't 64-bit since Visual Studio doesn't allow 64 bit inline assembly at all. This pretty much eliminates `mov ax, [rsi]` as an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google the error message.  The answer is [right there in MS's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zyca2kh.aspx) (the first google hit).

> illegal reference to 16-bit data in 'identifier'
>
> A 16-bit register is used as an index or base register. The compiler
>   does not support referencing 16-bit data. 16-bit registers cannot be
>   used as index or base registers when compiling for 32-bit code.

The first paragraph is a bit confusing, because it sounds like the problem is a 16bit operand size, rather than the 16bit address size.  But the second paragraph makes it clear: it refuses to use the address-size prefix to assemble something like `mov ax, [si]`, because ignoring the upper16 of an address is not a useful thing to ever do in inline asm.

They've decided it's better to catch typos / errors like that at compile time than to emit code that crashes.

Probably just change the line to `mov ax, [tab]`.  You're not gaining anything from storing the address in `esi`, since you don't modify it.

Comment: @Joshua: Yes it does, in 32bit but not 64bit.  Like Jester and Michael Petch said in comments.  `67 66 8b 04           mov    ax,WORD PTR [si]`.  Address size and operand-size prefixes.  That's disassembler output from `yasm -f elf32 && objdump -Mintel -d`